# Getting max values from pandas multiindex dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

Im trying to retrieve only the max values (including the multi index values) from a pandas dataframe that has multiple indexes. The dataframe I have is generated via a groupby and column selection ('tOfmAJyI') like this:

```
df.groupby('id')['tOfmAJyI'].value_counts()

Out[4]: 
id     tOfmAJyI
3      mlNXN       4
       SSvEP       2
       hCIpw       2
5      SSvEP       2
       hCIpw       1
       mlNXN       1
11     mlNXN       2
       SSvEP       1
...
```

What I would like to achieve is to get the max values including their corresponding index values. So something like:

```
id     tOfmAJyI
3      mlNXN       4
5      SSvEP       2
11     mlNXN       2
...
```

Any ideas how I can achieve this? I was able to get the id and max value but I'm still trying to get the corresponding value of 'tOfmAJyI'.

Comment: That was a really clever way to use `value_counts()`. Thanks :)

Answer (score 11):

`groupby` + `head`

```
df.groupby(level=0).head(1)
Out[1882]: 
id  tOfmAJyI
3   mlNXN       4
5   SSvEP       2
11  mlNXN       2
Name: V, dtype: int64
```

Or

```
df.loc[df.groupby(level=0).idxmax()]
Out[1888]: 
id  tOfmAJyI
3   mlNXN       4
5   SSvEP       2
11  mlNXN       2
Name: V, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Yes, first solution worked for me. 2nd one throws an error : NotImplementedError: Indexing a MultiIndex with a DataFrame key is not implemented.

Comment: @RamonAnkersmit then you can use 1st method ，multiple index always come with some funny error

Comment: The first solution doesn't return MAX, it returns just the 1st value which may not always be the max in the set.

Comment: I second what @GaryFrewin says, the first answer is just wrong I think

Comment: @GaryFrewin in this case , since he do value_counts which return the ordered series , so the first solution will work only for this, in general case we can add sort_values

Comment: @ffgg see above ~

Answer (score 4):

I can't understand why the practical solution for this problem isn't mentioned anywhere!?

Just do this:

For DataFrame DF with Keys KEY1,KEY2 where you want the max value for every KEY1, including KEY2:

```
DF.groupby('KEY1').apply(lambda x: x.max())
```

And you'll get the maximum for each KEY1 INCLUDING the Information which KEY2 holds the maximum, relative to each KEY1.

Comment: this does not use the multiindex, in fact it ignores it and it would not work without a .reset_index() call first

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar question and I don't think currently this question has a good answer.

My solution was this, I think it's cleaner:

```
df.groupby(level=0).nlargest(1)
```

this keeps the multiindex object and doesn't need a lambda function

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have previously sorted values, I think the best general answer is this variation of the one by ffggk which avoids duplicate index.

```
df.groupby(level=0, group_keys=False).nlargest(1)
```

Example:

```
>> df

id  tOfmAJyI
3   mlNXN       4
    SSvEP       2
    hCIpw       2
5   SSvEP       2
    hCIpw       1
    mlNXN       1
11  mlNXN       2
    SSvEP       1
Name: val, dtype: int64


>> df.groupby(level=0, group_keys=False).nlargest(1)

id  tOfmAJyI
3   mlNXN       4
5   SSvEP       2
11  mlNXN       2
Name: val, dtype: int64
```