# Using idxmax on a hierarchical dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I'm trying to find the index of the maximum values in multiple columns in a multi-index Pandas dataframe.

```
        Kommune  Upplands  Vallentuna...   Kiruna
Year    Party  
1973    M        0.9       29.2      ...   20     
        KD       15        10        ...   2 
        MP       1.1       4         ...   5     
        V        6         7         ...   8  
        SD       NaN       NaN       ...   NaN
        L        10.1      13.5      ...   8.8 
1976    M        1.8       29.2      ...   20     
        KD       16        10        ...   2 
        MP       10        4         ...   5     
        V        15        7         ...   8    
        SD       NaN       NaN       ...   NaN
        L        11.9      15        ...   18
...     ...      ...       ...       ...   ... 
...     ...      ...       ...       ...   ... 
2014    M        28        22        ...   29     
        KD       4.5       13        ...   5 
        MP       11        8         ...   9     
        V        1.9       5         ...   10    
        SD       20        10        ...   5
        L        19        25        ...   1
```

The desired output is

```
Kommune  Upplands  Vallentuna...   Kiruna
Year      
1973     KD        M         ...   M
1976     V         M         ...   M
...      ...       ...       ...   ...
2014     M         L         ...   M
```

I've tried using `groupby` (as suggested in a previous post on multi-index- [Getting max values from pandas multiindex dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48956379/getting-max-values-from-pandas-multiindex-dataframe)) but it returns a tuple for every position.

```
Kommune  Upplands          Vallentuna        ...   Kiruna
Year      
1973     (1973, KD)        (1973, M)         ...   (1973, M)
1976     (1976, V)         (1976, M)         ...   (1976, M)
...      ...               ...               ...   ...
2014     (2014, M)         (2014, L)         ...   (2014, M)
```

How do I get only the second element from each tuple? Or is there a more efficient way to find the indices?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like you need

```
df.stack().sort_values().groupby(level=[0,2]).tail(1).reset_index(level=1).Party.unstack()
Out[544]: 
     Upplands Vallentuna Kiruna
Year                           
1973       KD          M      M
1976       KD          M      M
```

Answer (score 0):

> How do I get only the second element from each tuple?

One solution is to extract the second element of each `tuple` via [`pd.DataFrame.applymap`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[(1, 2), (3, 4)], [(5, 6), (7, 8)]])

res = df.applymap(lambda x: x[1])

print(res)

   0  1
0  2  4
1  6  8
```

Or use the functional alternative:

```
from operator import itemgetter

res = df.applymap(itemgetter(1))
```